# Как сделать выпадающее меню элемента ul li на всю ширину экрана

Tags: css, html5

(Я еще новичок в web разработке)

Я сделал навигационную панель, но блок выпадающего меню (Header__Dropdown-content (см. ниже)) прикреплен к левому краю своего li.

Вот код:

```css
/* Отображение содержимого выпадающего списка (по умолчанию none) */

.Header__Dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100%;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Появление содержимого меню */

.Header__Dropdown ul li:hover .Header__Dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="Header__Dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="Header__Droplink" href="#">Value0</a>
      <div class="Header__Dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link0</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="Header__Droplink" href="#">value1</a>
      <div class="Header__Dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link0</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

И без JS пожалуйста, я не знаю его.

Comment: Во-первых, `hover` срабатывает  только над потомком... Во-вторых ты пытаешься навести мышь на элемент который скрыт. У тя  элементу `.Header__Dropdown-content` задано  свойство ` top:100%;`  ... ты от чего процент берешь??? У родителя нет высоты... (может это кусок верстки и у тя там все прописано... Я не знаю)  Далее  в данном случае что бы сработал `hover` можно его навесить на предыдущий элемент  `Header__Droplink:hover  ~ Header__Dropdown-content` тут важную рол играет тильда (~). Но самое важное хочу сказать Учи JS... Такие менюшки и навигации лучше реализовывать на JS

Comment: Учти что оператор тильда срабатывает только тогда, когда ты питаешься воздействовать на элемент по   иерархии ниже ,  и что еще важно у этих элементов должен быть один родитель

Comment: Особо ничего не понял, но понял то, что надо учить JS. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Глянь ответ... Если и щас не понятно... Уж прости... Подробнее ни как

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, hover срабатывает только над потомком...

```css
.parent,
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  opacity: 0;
  background: green;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="child">
</div>
```

Чтобы HOVER сработал над другим элементом, элемент должен быть иерархии ниже , и что еще важно у этих элементов должен быть один родитель

```css
.child_1,
.child_2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child_2 {
  opacity: 0;
  background: green;
}

.child_1:hover~.child_2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">
  </div>
  <div class="child_2">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Отображение содержимого выпадающего списка (по умолчанию none) */

.Header__Dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 100px;
  /*Изменил*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100%;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.Header__Droplink:hover~.Header__Dropdown-content {
  /*Изменил*/
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="Header__Dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="Header__Droplink" href="#">Value0</a>
      <div class="Header__Dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link0</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="Header__Droplink" href="#">value1</a>
      <div class="Header__Dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link0</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: мне просто нужно выпадающее меню как на этом сайте krisaveri.com